# scala iterate over JSON Array

Tags: json, scala, collections

I have a very simple JSON as below and I want to get `sJson[0], sJson[1]` objects, How can I achieve this ?

```
scala> val jsonA = "[{'foo': 4, 'bar': 'baz'},{'bla': 4, 'bar': 'bla'}]"
jsonA: String = [{'foo': 4, 'bar': 'baz'},{'bla': 4, 'bar': 'bla'}]

scala> val sJson = parseFull(jsonA)
sJson: Option[Any] = None

scala> println(sJson.toString())
None
```

[image]

Comment: Which library do you use for json parsing?

Comment: parseFull is from the scala.util.parsing.json.JSON package

Comment: Yup, `scala.util.parsing.j‌​son.JSON` package. I just want that `sJson` 's obj[0], obj[1] .. etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON notation wants you to surround variables with double quotes:

```
val jsonA = """[{"foo": 4, "bar": "baz"},{"bla": 4, "bar": "bla"}]"""
val sJson = parseFull(jsonA).get.asInstanceOf[List[Map[String,String]]] // List(Map(foo -> 4.0, bar -> baz), Map(bla -> 4.0, bar -> bla))
```

Comment: Get some exceptions `scala> val sJson = parseFull(jsonA).get
java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
  at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
  at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)`

Comment: hmm, what is your jsonA? the one I posted in the answer is parsing fine.

Comment: I see single quotes around the variables in your JSON in the image you just posted.

Comment: lol. Single quotes was the problem. Thanks Samar. It's working !

Comment: Samar, could you please do one more favour for me, my real quetion was to get first object from the JSON or list. I'm getting `scala> sJson(0)
<console>:23: error: Any does not take parameters
       sJson(0)` error. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121161/discussion-between-swapnil-and-samar).

Comment: See my answer for using an alternate library json4s which has a nice scala api and allows you to query your json in many ways (just like xml querying)

Answer (score 2):

While the scala.util.parsing.j‌son.JSON works well it is best to use an external library like [json4s](http://json4s.org/) which has a fluent scala api.

You can query json just like you query xml (like JsonPath).

**Below are the steps how you can use json4s for your need once you have it in your project.**

First add the following imports

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._
```

Now create a Jvalue by doing

```
val jsonA = """[{"foo": 4, "bar": "baz"},{"bla": 4, "bar": "bla"}]"""
val json = parse(jsonA)
```

Your json object is as

```
json: org.json4s.JValue = JArray(List(JObject(List((foo,JInt(4)), (bar,JString(baz)))), JObject(List((bla,JInt(4)), (bar,JString(bla))))))
```

To get the first (0th) child

```
val firstChild = (json)(0)

firstChild: org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue = JObject(List((foo,JInt(4)), (bar,JString(baz))))
```

To get a string representation of this firstChild

```
val firstChildString = compact(render(firstChild))

firstChildString: String = {"foo":4,"bar":"baz"}
```

See the section *Querying JSON* in [json4s](http://json4s.org/) home page for more.

**Note:** to import the jars you can use maven/gradle or import them into scala repl by using *:require* command.